# convert string to double in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

data table contain column named as Fld_primary. this column contain value like 0.00 it is double datatype in mysql table.i want store that datatable value in double variable. am always getting error when i convert to double datatype.

```
my code
------- 
Dim ds5 As dataset1.DTSUMDataTable = TA5.GetData(users)

Dim dttot As Double
dttot = CType(ds5("fld_primary").ToString, Double)
```

### Error

```
 Conversion from string "fld_primary" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Comment: Take a look what ds5("fld_primary").ToString returns. Can you post it?

Comment: Could be wrong here, but I don't believe the syntax used to reference that coulumn is correct. All the answers here are using incorrect code.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's complaining about this part of your code `ds5("fld_primary")` not the conversion of string to Double !  Try writing `Dim s As String = ds5("fld_primary")` and you will get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is actually: `ds5` expects an integer as a parameter, so using `ds5("fld_primary")` is not valid in your code. Perhaps you can try `ds5(0)("fld_primary")`.

After you fixed it, use

```
dttot = Double.Parse(whatever_string_you_should_put_here)
```

If you cannot ensure your string **must** be a valid `double`, then use `Double.TryParse`.

Comment: You're going to parse a whole column to double?

Comment: @KreepN I don't know what `DTSUMDataTable` is, even Google receives nothing

Comment: It's of a base type datatable.

Comment: am getting error like Conversion from string "fld_primary" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Comment: @Amulraj I know. Perhaps you can try `ds5(0)("fld_primary")`, just a guess

Answer (score 3):

Edited @ 3:01 AM with most recent screen caps.

Sometimes I find myself second guessing certain code based on people's answers, but I went ahead and took the time to check if the code that they are all using is even valid:
[image]

As you can see that code is a no go, so I used the correct code you see at the bottom there to reference a column.

However, if you wish to get a single cell use the chunk of code below that uses the foreach loop (the rest is my basic setup to show you how it works):

[image]

"Y" will equal the value of the datatable cell and you may convert it using the Double.Parse() method:

```
Dim y = Double.Parse(zDataRow("cat").ToString())
```

Be careful, if you have multiple rows you will notice that the value of y will change as it makes its way through all the rows.

Answer (score 3):

you can convert it using the [**`Convert`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class.

```
Dim dttot As Double = Convert.ToDouble(ds5("fld_primary"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using the 'Double.TryParse' way of converting as this handles any errors better and simply returns a boolean if succesful or not, using 'parse' will throw an exception which isnt anywhere near as elegant.

```
Dim dub as Double = 0
Double.TryParse("Your String Here", dub)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Double.TryParse(text,value)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
  For a=0 to yourgridview.rows.count-1
Yourgridview.rows(a).cells(targetcolumnnumber).value=cdbl(Yourgridview.rows(a).cells(targetcolumnnumber).value)
Next
```

Comment: A better answer would explain how this solves the asker's problem, and how this solution is different from those posed earlier.